# HideShow - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenos días Estimados

Intenté el método `HideShow` con una clase de ejemplo pero no funciona.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x;
        x=$(document);
        x.ready(inicio);

        function inicio(){
           //var x=$("#mostrar");
            $("#mostrar").click(muestrame);
            //var x=$("#ocultar");
            $("#mostrar")..click(ocultame);
        }

        function muestrame(){
            //var x=$("objetivo");
            $("objetivo").show(fast);
        }

        function ocultame(){
           //var x=$("objetivo");
            $("objetivo").hide(fast);
        }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #objetivo{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="mostrar" value="mostrar">
    <input type="button" id="ocultar" value="ocultar">
    <div id="objetivo"> Yo soy un div</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Que error te muestra?

Comment: Así a primera vista, veo alguna cosa rara en tu función inicio. Al llamar a las funciones `javascript`, no has puesto los paréntesis. Cuando llamas a Ocultame, tienes dos puntos. Mira a ver si solucionando estas cosas avanzas un poco mas

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Gracias Luis por los enlaces !

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando jQuery te recomiendo usarlo lo más que se pueda, además tienes varios errores.

1. En tu selector te faltaba el indicador de elemento para poder seleccionar, recuerda para seleccionar por `id` se usa `#` y para seleccionar por `class` se usa `.`
2. El parámetro que se pasa a los métodos de animación `.hide()` y `.show()` debe ir entre comillas

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mostrar").click(function(){
    $("#objetivo").show('fast');
  });

  $("#ocultar").click(function(){
    $("#objetivo").hide('fast');
  });
});
```

```css
#objetivo{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="mostrar" value="mostrar">
<input type="button" id="ocultar" value="ocultar">
<div id="objetivo"> Yo soy un div</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Camilo  !
Conoces una web online para verificar mi código ?

Slds

Comment: @LuisMiguelSanchezAlzamora si la respuesta fue tu solución te invito a que consideres marcarla como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores, además te invito también a que hagas el [tour] para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio...a que te refieres con "verificar mi código" ?

Answer (score 0):

Porque le estás pasando una variable `undefined` en el `.show()` o `.hide()` y deberías declararlo o bien pasarlo como `string` o `number` ya que jQuery acepta el string `"fast"` para mostrar u ocultar un elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```
$("objetivo").show("fast");

// lo muestra en 200 milisegundos
$("objetivo").show(200);
```

Vi que también preguntaste como validar el código, podés usar un IDE para trabajar con javascript como [Atom](https://atom.io/) o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) que validan código.

Comment: gracias uso el VSC !